# Get selected application name from share intent chooser?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, share, android-pendingintent

In my app I have share option to share data. I want to get the application name which the user selected to share the content.
As of API 21, it is possible with the help of Intent Sender

Below is my share code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My shared text");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
Intent receiver = new Intent(this, AppChooserReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null, pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
startActivity(chooser);
```

I created a receiver and it is declared in manifest. Below is the receiver code

```
public class AppChooserReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    for (String key : Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras()).keySet()) {
        try {
            ComponentName componentInfo = (ComponentName) intent.getExtras().get(key);
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            assert componentInfo != null;
            String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(componentInfo.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            Log.i("Selected Application Name", appName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I get the intent in the onreceive but the keyset is always null. Is there something I have missed out.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the source code, I tried and added

```
<receiver android:name="AppChooserReceiver" android:exported="false"/>
```

in AndroidManifest. and I get the app name

Comment: nice work. Works for me